# URL rewrite using .htaccess - opencart project

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

I'm looking for a solution for below URL rewrite rule

URL : `http://localhost/mysite/abc/index.php?route=product/category&path=1`

this has to be rewritten to

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php?route=product/category&path=1&store=abc
```

I have tried with the following

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ $2&store=$1 [L]
```

but it ended up in `/mysite/index.php&store=abc`

couldn't get the full $2

Comment: Check the `mod_rewrite` documentation about `QSA` flag

Comment: @zerkms, yes i have tried it also. but again getting /mysite/index.php&store=abc

Comment: show how exactly you tried it.

Comment: @zerkms Im very much new to htacees.. this is what i tried. RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ $2 [QSA,L]

Comment: And how do you know it ended up to `/mysite/index.php&store=abc`?

Comment: @zerkms in browser it shows a message with 404 error that /mysite/index.php&store=abc is not found

Comment: now I see: why do you put `&` in your rewrite rule? You want `?` there. The query parameters are separated from the URI by `?` not by `&`

Comment: yes but i want 'index.php?route=product/category&path=1' as $2 and $1 as abc, so finally appending it will make it a valid url i.e index.php?route=product/category&path=1&store=abc. so as i append it at the end i have it as '&store=abc'

Comment: "so as i append it at the end" -- it **does not** work that way. The left part of a rewrite rule **does not** match anything from a query string. So you need to: 1. Use `?` and specify your parameters after it 2. Automatically append what was there before using `QSA`

Comment: A small comment, but you may find this tool useful for testing: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/